# Lower bound on the largest restrained cubic subset

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, upper-lower-bounds

Consider an $n \times n \times n$ cube. I would like to consider subsets of points in the cube with the two following constraints:

1. Each row in the cube (in any of the three directions) has exactly 2 or 0 points.
2. If two points are in the same row (any of three), connect them with an edge. The subset must be connected by these edges.

It is easy to build such a set which is $\Omega(n)$, for instance a staircase, or stacking squares. Is it the case that these structures are also $O(n)$? Or is there an $\Omega(n^2)$ bound?

Building such a set would require adding a linear number of points for each added dimension, which is hard due to the first restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that these objects have been studied by David Eppstein, and the largest example for an $n \times n \times n$ cube is exactly the maximum $2n^2$.

To see the construction and other comments see:

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38462/lower-bound-on-the-largest-restrained-cubic-subset